# Discount on sale order based on quantity of product in odoo8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

In products how can I give discount based on quantity.Ex,Suppose if I given quantity 3 for x and discount is 30%.So if customer select the product x and quantity 3 in sale order the discount should fill with 30%.

Can anyone help if any existing module present or any assistance .

Comment: You can use pricelists for such behaviour. For the pricelist entries/rules you have to define identical rules with different minimum quantities.